# Is there any way to pass a generic when typing an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

*First of all, I feel like I'm on the wrong path to begin with.*

I have the following code:

```
export const fastMap = {};

export type FastMapOptions<S, T> = {
  key: string;
  value: T;
  selector: (state: RootState) => T;
  dispatch: (state: S, action: PayloadAction<any>) => void;
};

export const addToFastMap = <S, T>(options: FastMapOptions<S, T>) => {
  const { key, value, selector, dispatch } = options;

  fastMap[key] = {
    value,
    selector,
    atom: atom({ key, default: value }),
    dispatch
  };
};
```

As you can see, `fastMap` isn't really anything. However, my `options` (`value, selector, atom, dispatch`) are clearly typed. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get `fastMap` to play nice. If I were to do:

```
addToFastMap<SliceState, number>({
  key: "margin",
  value: 20,
  selector: (state: RootState) => state.properties.margin,
  dispatch: marginUpdatedReducer
});
```

And then simply access `fastMap['margin']`, it will not be able to tell me anything about what's in there, however, it's clear that the `value` is a `number`, the `key` is a `string` and so on.

Naturally, I'm using generics, as I need them here to be able to correctly type these arguments.

Is there any way to get the correct typings in this case?

Comment: "flatMap['margin']" is this a typo ?

Comment: @Cerceis Hey, not sure what you mean. I updated the function names. The `addToFastMap` simply adds an item with the `margin` key to the `fastMap` object.

Comment: Give `fastMap` a type, currently, it has type `{}` which does not accept anything

Comment: @DanielIvory You typed "flatMap",instead of "fastMap", is that a typo or are you using flatMap() from Array. That need clarification. Either way it does not make sense. Also your fastMap indeed need a type on declaration..

Comment: @TrashCan Well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can achieve the desired behaviour by using a building pattern like this.

```
export type FastMapOptions<S, T> = {
    value: T;
    selector: (state: S) => T;
    dispatch: (state: S, action: PayloadAction<any>) => void;
};


function fastMapBuilder<T extends Record<string, any>>(inital: T) {
    const fastMap = inital
    const self = {
        fastMap,
        add<K extends string, State, Return>(key: K, options: FastMapOptions<State, Return>) {
            const next: T & { [Key in K]: { key: Key } & FastMapOptions<State, Return> } = { ...inital, [key]: { ...options, key } }
            return fastMapBuilder(next)
        },
        build() {
            return fastMap
        }
    }
    return self
}
const fastMap = fastMapBuilder({})
    .add("hover", { value: "idk", selector: (s: string) => "", dispatch: (s, a: {}) => { } })
    .add("over", { value: 0, selector: (s: string) => 0, dispatch: (s, a: {}) => { } }).build()

//{
//    hover: {
//        key: "hover";
//    } & FastMapOptions<string, string>;
//} & {
//    over: {
//        key: "over";
//    } & FastMapOptions<string, number>;
//}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=8&ts=4.7.4#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)

Comment: I must say that, while it works, it's definitely an absolute unit of complexity. Thanks a lot. It fixed my issue and I *guess* I learned some things (primarily that I don't know TS as well as I should).

Comment: I'll provide an detailed explanation, but I'm busy at the moment so you have to wait a few days. Sorry for that